# ¿Cuál es la diferencia de systemctl reboot y reboot?

Tags: linux, unix

Tengo entendido que `reboot` es para reiniciar el pc, mientras que `systemctl reboot` es hacer lo mismo pero con systemd, pero no sé cuál es la diferencia al ahora de usar uno u otro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero creo que hay que explicar cosas que parece que no están relacionadas.

**systemd**, **SysVinit** son un conjunto de demonios encargados de la inicialización de un sistema operativo y de administrar los procesos del sistema después del arranque.

**systemd**, y otros como **upstart**, etc, surgió como reemplazo de **SysVinit**.

Puedes ver que son los primeros procesos que se ejecutan.

```
ps --pid=1 f
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    1 ?        Ss     0:00 /init ro

ps --pid=1 f
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    1 ?        Ss     3:46 /lib/systemd/systemd --system --deserialize 20
```

Ambos poseen programas (o enlaces simbólicos) para trabajar con el manejo de los procesos del sistema. Apagar, detener, reiniciar, el sistema o cancelar estas tareas.

Cuando en un sistema, que utilizara SysVinit, se utilizaban los programas como `reboot` o `poweroff`, estos eran enlaces simbólicos al programa `halt` y hacían que este programa actuara de forma diferente según con el nombre que había sido invocado. Al mandarlos a llamar, se cambiaba el nivel de ejecución (*runlevel*) a 1, para el modo de single-user o nivel de mantenimiento y se procede a correr procesos según lo que se estipule en sus scripts de nivel de ejecución.

En cambio, en los sistemas que usan **systemd**, se utiliza el programa `systemctl` que controla `systemd`.

Algo análogo, a los enlaces simbólicos, pasa con el programa `poweroff` y demás que se utilizan para mantener una relación con los de **SysVinit**

```
$ ls -l $(command -v "poweroff")
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Jul 30 16:31 /sbin/poweroff -> /bin/systemctl
$ ls -l $(command -v "shutdown")
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Jul 30 16:31 /sbin/shutdown -> /bin/systemctl
$ ls -l $(command -v "reboot")
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Jul 30 16:31 /sbin/reboot -> /bin/systemctl
$ ls -l $(command -v "halt")
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Jul 30 16:31 /sbin/halt -> /bin/systemctl
$ ls -l $(command -v "runlevel")
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Jul 30 16:31 /sbin/runlevel -> /bin/systemctl
$ ls -l $(command -v "telinit")
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Jul 30 16:31 /sbin/telinit -> /bin/systemctl
```

Todos son enlaces simbólicos al programa `/bin/systemctl` (en el caso de un sistema que use systemd).

Parte de lo anterior fue para mostrar que "apagar" o "reiniciar" la máquina, es un proceso que depende de un conjunto de programas de inicialización (upstart, systemd, init, etc). Así que apagar o reiniciar son tareas y conceptos dependientes de cada sistemas de administración.

Aunque la respuesta corta sería que utilizaras el comando `readlink -f $(command -v reboot)` donde `command -v programa` es un *built-in* de bash que, entre varias utilidades, permite mostrar información de cómo se interpreta el nombre de programa pasado como parámetro. `readlink` es un programa que resuelve nombres de archivos o enlaces simbólicos, y con el parámetro `-f` o `-e` sigue cada enlace simbólico al que es referido el argumento.

Comment: Genial, pero que significa que `readlink` es un programa que resuelva nombres de archivos o enlaces simbólicos

Comment: Los sigue hasta determinado punto. Por ejemplo, si tienes instalado google chrome, trata de utilizar `readlink $(command -v "google-chrome")` y juega con los parámetros `-f` o sin parámetros. Corriéndolo sin parámetros no te devuelve el nombre del ejecutable en la carpeta /opt, con el parámetro `-f` o `-e` si te devuelve el nombre del último archivo al que hace referencia.

Comment: Para más información, revisa `man 1 readlink`